# How to reference a bean's property inside servlet-context?

Tags: java, spring

I am new to Java and I am working on a Spring MVC project.
we have a servlet-context where we store information we are going to need at runtime. I have a set of URLs that are important on my system and they are all based on a base URL that is also defined on the servlet context, like this:

```
<bean id="applicationConfiguration"
        class="example.ApplicationConfig">
        <property name="baseUrl" value="http://localhost:8080/"></property>
    </bean>
```

Now, I have a second bean in which I would like to reference the baseUrl:

```
   <bean id="menu"
            class="example.Menu">
            <property name="entry1name" value="entry1"></property>
            <property name="entry1value" value="<baseUrl>"></property>
            <property name="entry2name" value="entry2"></property>
            <property name="entry2value" value="<baseUrl>/page2"></property>
        </bean>
```

The second bean is a little bit simpler than the real one, to focus on the problem.

I would like to reference the baseUrl property, so I am searching and trying things like

```
${applicationConfiguration.baseUrl}

@applicationConfiguration.baseUrl
```

using

```
<property name="entry1value" ref="applicationConfiguration.baseUrl"></property>
```

and so on.

The first two are used as string, not "resolved".
The second one does not work because .baseUrl is not a bean.

Is there any way that I can reference the property to use it as a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to define baseUrl as another bean in that case

```
<bean id="baseUrl" class="java.lang.String">
  <constructor-arg value="http://localhost:8080/"/>
</bean>
```

and then use it reference

for example

```
<property name="baseUrl" ref="baseUrl/">
```

in your particular example it is more suitable to use `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` instead of defining separate bean per property

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">

    <property name="location">
        <value>yourApp.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and then refer properties directly in application context by property key name for example

```
<property name="baseurl" value="${baseurl}" />
```

provided that your `yourApp.properties` is placed on root of classpath and it has a following property

```
baseurl=somevalue
```

Comment: That is great! If I take the first approach, am I able to concatenate things? 
for instance
baseUrl/myPage?

Comment: no you can only specify reference of bean in first approach, you cannot concat value to its resolved value in xml

Comment: but second approach can do it

Comment: Ok, the second approach is better, I will use it. Thanks a lot, it was a life saver!